# Is there a way to have Excel save as a pdf automatically to a folder when you press PRINT?

Tags: vba, excel

The operators need to print a physical copy of a sheet but I also wanted a pdf to automatically be generated and saved in a mapped drive on our network. Is this possible? (Excel 2013/2016)

Best Case:  Press Print and It prints a hardcopy as well as a pdf to a folder (possibly naming by sales order # - which is a value on the sheet, or by date&time)

Worst Case: Click SAVE and automatically Printing a hard copy  and creating a pdf (auto generating filename as stated above) while ALSO automatically

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can do the best case. Just loop through the sheets from your workbook and put them into a collection, such as a dico or an array, and then loop into this collection to both save and print each sheet. Next time, post your code, it will be better.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible, look at *[Workbook.BeforePrint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195836.aspx)* Event Occurs before the workbook or anything in it is printed

*Paste code in the ThisWorkbook module*

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)

    ' Your Code here

End Sub
```